# Is it possible to model real cities in the new Cities: Skyline?

Tags: cities-skylines

Is it possible to model real cities in the new Cities: Skyline ? By that, I mean to recreate the look of the city so it would resemble an aerial of a real city like London or Chicago.

Obviously to do that you would need to make buildings look like real buildings in the city in question. For example the Chicago skyline looks like this:

[image: Chicago skyline]

Is it possible to replicate this look in Cities: Skyline?

Answer (score 4):

Of course it would be possible, but if you wanted the exact skyline of Chicago, you would have to get every building asset modded to look like their realistic counterparts. The modding community is so huge for this game that no doubt somebody is probably already working on all that as we speak. As far as terrain goes you can use tools like http://terrain.party to generate "height maps" and import them into Cities: Skylines

Comment: Is "modding" an asset something an ordinary player can do, or does it take a lot of specialized expertise or programming?

Comment: Creating a model from scratch yourself would require knowledge of and software for 3D modelling, texturing, etc.

Comment: @TylerDurden There is an ingame asset editor, but I'm not sure how what it's robustness to use difficulty ratio is.

Comment: you could try to use similar looking buildings instead

Answer (score 2):

### Map Terrain

Also there is a mode: [Cimtographer](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=416064574) - which allows you to import maps in [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/49.15343/16.62935) data format into game, including road network.

<sup>Note: This mode provides both way (import/export). So when you improve your imported city, you can export city into OSM map data and then render it in any OSM map renderer like Mapnik into pickture .. cool yea?</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I have seen some people doing this. They create their maps using a [background real map](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=421400880&searchtext=Overlay) image to have a template for their roads and create hight maps of the city. Creating the buildings is only one aspect, the correct scale is also challenging.

You will find a very high level community on facebook called: "SkylinesNation - A Cities: Skylines Guild".
So if you are interested in more, you may want to get in touch.

[image: Building LINZ]

[image: ImageOverlay]
[image: Building Atlanta]